# Two dependent Bernouilli trials with probability $p$ and $q$

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

Say you have two Bernouilli trials which have normally probability $p$ and $q$ respectively. If they are independent, the probability of having 1,1 is $p \times q$. Of having 0,0 is $(1-p)\times(1-q)$ , 1,0 = $(p)\times(1-q)$

But now, if both trials are not independent. The probability of seeing 1,1 is probably more than  $p \times q$ and of  seeing 1,0 is less than $(p)\times(1-q)$.

How have people modeled this previously ?

Comment: Commonly, the _parameter_ of a Bernoulli random variable is the probability that the random variable has value $1$, not $0$.

Comment: "The probability of seeing $1,1$ is probably more than.." Why? If $B_2:=1-B_1$ then the probability on $B_1=1=B_2$ is $0$.

Comment: Because in the extreme case with perfect dependence, you only have 1,1 and 0,0 but not 0,1 and 1,0.

Comment: You need an extra parameter.  For example if $P((1,1))=r$ then $P((1,0))=p-r$, $P((0,1))=q-r$, and $P((0,0))=1-p-q+r$: all four need to be non-negative, putting a constraint on $r$.

Comment: @Henry Thank you, do you have a paper I could read about this ?

Comment: @madreblu There are two cases of what you call perfect dependence: $B_1=B_2$ and $B_1=1-B_2$.

Comment: @Henry but what if the correlation is zero, why don't we fall back to the default case?

Comment: @drhab I know but what about the intermediate cases.

Comment: If the correlation is zero then $r=pq$

Comment: @henry and if it isn't ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Omega:=\{\langle0,0\rangle,\langle0,1\rangle,\langle1,0\rangle,\langle1,1\rangle\}$ and let $\mathcal A:=\wp(\Omega)$.

Then determine the probability $P$ by stating that $P(\{\langle i,j\rangle\})=p_{i,j}$ where $p_{i,j}\geq0$ and $$p_{0,0}+p_{0,1}+p_{1,0}+p_{1,1}=1$$

Note that this equality makes it possible to practicize exactly $3$ parameters as Henry suggests in his comment.

The functions $B_1,B_2:\Omega\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ prescribed by $\langle i,j\rangle\mapsto i$ and $\langle i,j\rangle\mapsto j$ respectively are both Bernouilli-distributed.

This with $P(B_1=1)=p_{1,0}+p_{1,1}$ and $P(B_2=1)=p_{0,1}+p_{1,1}$.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the nature of the dependence by introducing conditional probabilities