# $P(X=Y)$ for two dependent random variables

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

> The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are both $Be(1/2) = Bin(1,1/2)$-distributed and have correlation coefficient $1/2$. Determine $P(X=Y)$.

I would really appreciate some hints on this, cause I'm completely lost. I'd wanna work with this using conditioning, but there is no joint distribution to work with here - or is there? I don't find any material on "recovering" a joint distribution function from the marginal ones. I would have guessed the joint distribution might be multinomial, but that can't be the case here since the correlation is not negative. On stackexchange it appears [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195816/two-dependent-bernouilli-trials-with-probability-p-and-q) question is closest to mine, but I can't quite understand the answers given there.

Comment: Yep, missed that part of the question. @Ant

Answer (score 6):

Hint: the correlation coefficient of $X,Y$ is $\frac{E[(X-1/2)(Y-1/2)]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X) \operatorname{Var}(Y)}}$. Here the variances are both $1/4$, so $E[(X-1/2)(Y-1/2)]=\frac{1}{8}$. Try to compute the joint distribution from here.

A more detailed hint:

$$E[(X-1/2)(Y-1/2)]=E[XY]-1/2E[X]-1/2E[Y]+1/4=E[XY]-1/4=1/8.$$

Hence $E[XY]=3/8$. But $E[XY]=P(X=1 \text{ and } Y=1)$. This is one of the four numbers we need to compute to find the joint distribution. How can we find the other three?

Comment: I was thinking about this but you can only recover $P(X=1, Y=1) = \frac 12$ from this.. It's not entirely clear how to find the other probabilities

Comment: @Ant The above uses $E[XY]$ to compute $P(X=1,Y=1)$. Given that, the rows and colmuns of the joint PMF need to sum to the values of the marginal PMFs, which are also known. This gives the off-diagonal entries, which then gives the other diagonal entry. (Basically, the given information about the marginal distributions, along with the normalization condition, gives 3 linear equations in 4 unknowns; the correlation coefficient gives us a fourth equation.)

Comment: Oh my. Thank you.. such an idiot :-)

Comment: @Ian Thanks! Unfortunately I'm still clueless. Should I work with the fact that $C(X,Y) = \sum_{j,k} (j-1/2)(k-1/2) p_{X,Y}(j,k)$? That is, $1/2 = p(0,0)-p(0,1)-p(1,0)+p(1,1)$...

Comment: @ErikVesterlund I expanded a bit.

Comment: Thanks Ian. That is very clever I must say! Now all I have to do is calculate the actual probability $P(X=Y)=P(X-Y=0)$, which I'm unsure of. My guess is to sum the joint pmf over those $j,k$ whose difference is zero, i.e. $\sum_{j-k=0} p_{X,Y}(j,k) = p_{X,Y}(0,0)+p_{X,Y}(1,1)$, however I'm not sure if this takes the dependence into account, should I perhaps condition $X$ on $Y$, somehow?

Comment: @ErikVesterlund Nope. It is easier than that. What is $P (X=0) $ (say) in terms of the joint distribution?

Comment: Well I suppose $P(X=0) = p_{X,Y}(0,0)+p_{X,Y}(0,1)$... not sure where this is going :D

Comment: Sorry, I should have said $P (X=1) $. You get an equation with only one unknowm!

Comment: I'm not following. $P(X=1) = p_{X,Y}(1,0)+p_{X,Y}(1,1) = 1/8 + 3/8$, I don't know how to go from that to calculating $P(X=Y)$?

Comment: OK, so now you have $p_{X,Y}(1,0)$ which you didn't have before. Now you know $P(Y=1)=p_{X,Y}(0,1)+p_{X,Y}(1,1)=1/8+3/8$ by the same argument. Now you have three of the four numbers in the joint distribution. How do you get the last one?

Comment: Oh. Yeah I have all the $p_{X,Y}(j,k)$ already, thanks to your earlier post. I got: $p(1,1)=p(0,0)=3/8$ and $p(0,1)=p(1,0)=1/8$. What I meant earlier is, when calculating $P(X=Y)$ as $p(0,0)+p(1,1)=6/8$, is that the correct way, or is that "solution" false because it does not take into account the dependence between $X$ and $Y$? (indeed, I don't even know whether or not it takes the dependence into account.)

Comment: @ErikVesterlund That's correct. All of the dependence is already captured through these four numbers. And indeed you do have dependence, because for instance $P(X=1,Y=1)=3/8$ but $P(X=1)P(Y=1)=1/4$.